# How to Interact with an Encrypted SQS Queue? KMS Key Access not Working

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I am trying to interact with an encrypted SQS queue via Java SDK.

The application is sending a response:

`AmazonSQSException: The ciphertext refers to a customer master key that does not exist, does not exist in this region, or you are not allowed to access.`

However, I can see that the key does exist and I am attempting to give proper access.

I assume there is some error in the way I have done this. Please see below -

**SDK Interaction**

Intention: Reads from one queue and writes to another. Fails after line 4, when attempting to receive messages.

```
public void replayQueue(QueuePair queuePair) {
    ReceiveMessageRequest messageRequest = new ReceiveMessageRequest()
            .withQueueUrl(queuePair.getDlq());
    log.info("Constructed receive request: " + messageRequest.toString());
    sqs.receiveMessage(messageRequest).getMessages().stream()
            .forEach(message -> {
                log.info("Inside stream. Message: " + message.toString());
                SendMessageRequest request = new SendMessageRequest()
                        .withQueueUrl(queuePair.getSource())
                        .withMessageBody(message.getBody());
                log.info("Send request: " + request);
                SendMessageResult result = sqs.sendMessage(request);
                log.info("Sent messages to " + queuePair.getSource() + " with result of: " + result.toString());
                    }
            );
}
```

**Key Creation**

The key is created in another microservice's template and works fine for that service.

```
ApplicationKmsKeyForSqs:
Type: AWS::KMS::Key
Properties:
  Description: Encrypts messages published to SQS from SNS
  KeyPolicy:
    Version: 2012-10-17
    Id: !Sub ${DNSEndPoint}-application-${Environment}-sqs-kms-key
    Statement:
    - Sid: Enable IAM User Permission
      Effect: Allow
      Principal:
        AWS: !Sub 'arn:aws:iam::${AWS::AccountId}:root'
      Action:
      - kms:*
      Resource: '*'
    - Sid: Allow SQS to use the key
      Effect: Allow
      Principal:
        Service: sqs.amazonaws.com
      Action:
      - kms:GenerateDataKey*
      - kms:Decrypt
      Resource: '*'

ApplicationKMSKeyAlias:
Type: AWS::KMS::Alias
Properties:
  AliasName: !Sub 'alias/application-${Environment}-sqs-kms-key'
  TargetKeyId: !Ref ApplicationKmsKeyForSqs
```

I can see that the key exists in the AWS Console and has the proper alias.

**Giving Permissions to the Application**

This policy should give my application permissions to use the key created in the other microservice.

```
ApplicationPolicy:
Type: AWS::IAM::Policy
Properties:
  PolicyName: app-policy
  PolicyDocument:
    Version: 2012-10-17
    Statement:
      - Effect: Allow
        Action:
          - sqs:*
        Resource: !Sub arn:aws:sqs:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:*${Environment}*
      - Effect: Allow
        Action:
          - kms:Encrypt
          - kms:Decrypt
          - kms:GenerateDataKey*
          - kms:*
        Resource: !Sub arn:aws:kms:us-east-1:${AWS::AccountId}:alias/application-${Environment}-sqs-kms-key
```

In light of this, it looks to me that:

1. The key clearly exists
2. It's in the right region
3. I am giving it access (or attempting to)

So I am wondering if there is something else I'm missing. Is the key supposed to be sent as part of the request? Is something in the way I am giving it access wrong?

Any tips would be appreciated.

Comment: Everything seems fine. It might be some simple typo or mistake. Are you sure the policy is attached to the execution role? Are you able to perform these actions with [IAM Policy Simulator](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_policies_testing-policies.html)?

Comment: @kichik I've discovered it's trying to use an old key for these messages. I'm wondering if there's some weird interaction - perhaps the messages were encrypted with an old key and the new one won't allow them to decrypt? Still not sure on the solution but I suspect it is not anything wrong in the policies written above.

Comment: @8t12c7081, have you figured out that? Would you share the solution here?

Answer (score 2):

In your implementation of the KMS Key, you're only providing access to SQS to decrypt using the KMS key. Since SQS is doing the encryption with server-side encryption this needs to be extended so the sqs can encrypt as well.

```
- Sid: Allow SQS to use the key
  Effect: Allow
  Principal:
    Service: sqs.amazonaws.com
  Action:
  - kms:GenerateDataKey*
  - kms:Decrypt
  - kms:Encrypt
  Resource: '*'
```

The lambda function then needs permission to the KMS Key to kms:Decrypt and kms:GenerateDataKey.

Amazon documentation:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-key-management.html#send-to-encrypted-queue